# Vimeo Upload with Ruby On Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, vimeo

I have been trying to figure out how to integrate vimeo upload with my rails app. I want to get a vimeo business plan. My app will allow people to upload videos to my website that my vimeo account will host. The video submission form should be on my website and send them to vimeo to upload. I will then use the vimeo id to embed on the show page.

I imagine this works though api, but not sure how to code an upload form that can upload the video then embed it into my video show view page.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could start having a look at: https://github.com/matthooks/vimeo . 
Also you could find some useful info on vimeo official documentation: http://developer.vimeo.com/apis/advanced/upload .
There is also a simple example described here: http://jakenelsondooley.com/2013/08/19/115/ .
I hope this helps.
I am thinking of implementing the same functionalities or just allowing users to post video on vimeo with their accounts from a third party application that I have developed. If I find something else I would surely let you know.